# Vuescroll. Связать два скролла между собой

Tags: vue.js

есть два блока со скролами, надо что бы при скроле одного, скролился и др блок, ширины одинаковые. в один контейнер поместить нельзя.
Использую библиотеку https://vuescrolljs.yvescoding.me/. Сижу и ищу в доке как можно указывать положение скролла, но не нашла, либо не вижу. Нашла только такой параметр, но он только при загрузке стр `initialScrollX`. Есть событие `handleScrollBody`, там могу получить на сколько был сдвинут скролл. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно связать эти скролы, скролю один, на такое же расстояние скролится другой. Скролл по горизонтали

```js
const BaseTable = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
        updateMe: '',
        range: '1',
        ops: {
          scrollPanel: {
            initialScrollX: 0,
            initialScrollY: 1,
            locking: true
          },
        },
    },
    watch: {
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
      handleScrollBody(vertical, horizontal, nativeEvent) {
        console.log('horizontal2', horizontal)
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.block1,
.block2 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 2500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="block1">
      <vue-scroll class="scroll-table" :ops="ops">
        <div class="content">{{ range }}</div>
      </vue-scroll>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <vue-scroll @handle-scroll="handleScrollBody" class="scroll-table" :ops="ops">
        <div class="content">{{ range }}</div>
      </vue-scroll>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuescroll@4.17.5/dist/vuescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как у плагина выставлять положение скролла я так и не нашла. пошла другим путем

```js
const BaseTable = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
        updateMe: '',
        range: '1',
        ops: {
          scrollPanel: {
            initialScrollX: 0,
            initialScrollY: 1,
            locking: true
          },
        },
    },
    watch: {
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
      handleScrollHeader(vertical, horizontal, nativeEvent) {
        const scrollProgres = horizontal.scrollLeft
        const headerBlock = document.querySelector('.block2 .__panel')
        headerBlock.scrollLeft = scrollProgres
      },
      handleScrollBody(vertical, horizontal, nativeEvent) {
        const scrollProgres = horizontal.scrollLeft
        const headerBlock = document.querySelector('.block1 .__panel')
        headerBlock.scrollLeft = scrollProgres
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.block1,
.block2 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 2500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="block1">
      <vue-scroll class="scroll-table" :ops="ops" @handle-scroll="handleScrollHeader">
        <div class="content">{{ range }}</div>
      </vue-scroll>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <vue-scroll @handle-scroll="handleScrollBody" class="scroll-table" :ops="ops">
        <div class="content">{{ range }}</div>
      </vue-scroll>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuescroll@4.17.5/dist/vuescroll.min.js"></script>
```